# CASE statement example

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can someone please help me identify the correct syntax for `CASE` statement with Spark SQL? I tried the following:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE circle WHEN ("Panjab") THEN 2 END
FROM
  siteinfo
```

where `circle` is a valid column name. However, I'm still unable to determine the correct approach.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```sql
SELECT IF(circle='Panjab', 2, 0) FROM siteinfo
```

Comment: Hello, I understand if syntax. Want to use case with Spark 1.1, are you aware of the syntax

Answer (score 0):

the correct case when syntax：

```sql
SELECT
  CASE circle= "Panjab" THEN 2 END
FROM
  siteinfo
```

or

```sql
SELECT
  CASE circle= "Panjab" THEN 2 else 'some other value' END
FROM
  siteinfo
```